# How many times do I get the chance to earn the "75 wins" rewards, in Call of Duty: Black Ops 3?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-3

In Call of Duty: Black Ops 3, once u tap the CONTRACT icon, you will be able to complete the "75 wins" reward.

Is this repeatable, or can you only get the rewards once?

Comment: Be sure to see if my answer has helped and possibly accept or give feedback for future people.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, you can only complete the contract and obtain the reward (10 rare supply drops and 1 weapon bribe) once.

[image]

As shown above, Treyarch and Activision are going to be releasing an update where you will be able to complete daily and weekly contracts for rewards. Which is the reason why it says "*coming soon*" in the boxes.

Comment: i could have added an image of the completed result but i didn't for two reasons:

1. I do not have a functioning phone at the moment 
2. I'm pretty sure that when you get to 75, you will see that it's not repeatable.